# Angular4: How to bind to function result in ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Given this code:

```
<div *ngFor='let loc of user.locations | async'>
    <div *ngFor='let day of days'>
        <div *ngFor='let data of get_data_observable(loc, day) | async'>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is connecting to a Firebase database.

```
get_data_observable(loc, day) => this.db.list(`/users/${this.auth.uid}/times/${loc.$key}/${day}`)
```

I believe a new observable is being created every time Angular checks the in-most ngFor, causing massive performance issues. I want ngFor to bind to the result of `get_data_observable(loc, day)` rather than the expression. Then it would be subscribing to one observable that doesn't change.

What's the best way around this?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14826 discusses the problem, but the suggested solution is too difficult to implement (assigning to a static variable), because there is 3 levels of nesting with too many possible results.

Comment: SwitchMap maybe? http://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-switchmap-operator/

Comment: I'm not sure if that will solve this. The issue is further documented here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2449 but seems like they never ended up allowing a template based solution for this. Will have to create a separate component...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by enclosing the in-most ngFor in a component, and giving it the functions arguments as its input. Since the arguments themselves never change (per iteration) then only one observable is created for each in-most item.

```
<app-day [loc]='loc' [day]='day'></app-avail-day>
```

And

```
export class DayComp {
    obs
    @Input() loc
    @Input() day

    ngOnChanges(){
        this.obs = get_data_observable(this.loc, this.day)
    }
}
```